# int showing up as std::basic_ostream<char> in operator==

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am working on a program that will encrypt and decrypt a Rails-Cipher. In the process of doing so I ran into an error where the following code never gets to the "inc != inc" line.

After looking at the error messages I found out this was due to the fact that the "line" variable was seen as a std::basic_ostream. I have been looking around and cannot figure out why. I declare it as an int. Key is an int in the RailsCipher class. I put my code I am struggling with and also the errors that I got out of it.

CODE:

```
string RailsCipher::encrypt()
{
    string array[key];
    bool inc = true;
    int line = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < data.length(); ++p, inc ? ++line : --line)
    {
        array[line].push_back(data[p]);
        cout << line == 0;
        cout << line == (key - 1);
        if (line == 0 || line == (key - 1))
            inc != inc;
    }
    string encrypted;
    for (int i = 0; i < key; i++)
        encrypted += array[i];
    return encrypted;
}
```

ERRORS:

```
rail.cpp: In member function ‘std::string RailsCipher::encrypt()’:
rail.cpp:27:22: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘int’)
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                      ^
rail.cpp:27:22: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iosfwd:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:214:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:214:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:128:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
     operator==(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:128:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:133:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_CharT>&)
     operator==(const allocator<_Tp>&, const allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/allocator.h:133:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2486:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2486:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2493:5: note: template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)
     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2493:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2507:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2507:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2519:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2519:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from rail.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:204:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
     operator==(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>& __a,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:204:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
rail.cpp:27:33: note:   ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>’
         cout << line == (key - 1);
                                 ^
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `cout << (line == key - 1);`

Comment: I am not asking whether that's the line where you get the error, I am asking whether you have tried what I have suggested.

Comment: Found that out by your answer, sorry for the blunder.

Comment: No problem, don't feel sorry, it happens to everyone, it happens all the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the "line" variable is *not* seen as a `std::basic_ostream`.

The error `no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘int’)` means that the compiler thinks that you are trying to apply the `==` operator between `cout << line` and `(key - 1)`. As in: `(cout << line) == (key - 1)`.

You see, `cout` is of type `std::basic_ostream`, and the result of `cout << line` is also of type `std::basic_ostream`, so as to allow you to keep appending stuff to the stream by repeating the `>>` operator.

It is simply a matter of operator precedence: the `>>` operator has higher precedence than the `==` operator.  So, the compiler first evaluates `cout << line`, which is of type `std::basic_ostream`, and then it tries to evaluate that plus `== (key - 1)`.  Which does not compute.

So, you need some parentheses to tell the compiler that you want the `==` operator to be applied between `line` and `(key - 1)`, and the result of that to be output to the stream.

So, what you need is `cout << (line == key - 1)`.

(I think that the parentheses in your original `line == (key - 1)` were unnecessary.)

Comment: You are correct. I am unable to up-vote this answer for 3 more minutes. Thanks for quickly answering. I also appreciate that you did not criticize my major oversight. That being said, can you see why this would cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: Oh, no problem.  I am not sure about the segmentation fault, it is not in the original question.  And by quickly scanning through your code, I cannot see any obvious problem that would cause a segfault. (Only be aware that `inc != inc;` will probably not do what you think.)  I would suggest that you start a new question about that.

Comment: You probably want `inc = !inc;`

Comment: Understandable, thanks anyways. Will probably post another question.